# List commit-mode of files in commit in git

Tags: git

Is there a way to make git output a list of files of a commit like

```
git diff --name-only b242091~1 b242091
```

, but that will print an additional column with the mode in which the files were added (new, deleted, changed, ...).

Or put differently: Is there something like

```
git status --porcelain
```

that can be used on commits?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: I can't reproduce your Problem, when using `git diff --name-only`, only pathes are shown (git version 1.9.1)

Comment: Maybe you have something in your git config which produces the extra output (try `git config -l` to show it)?

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke I think you misunderstood me: I WANT extra output (see my answer below). Sorry, english is not my mother's tongue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `git diff --name-status` is what you're looking for.

```
$ git diff --name-status commit1 commit2
M       path/to/modified-file
D       path/to/deleted-file
A       path/to/added-file
```

The git-diff(1) man page lists all possible first column values and what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

Until now, the best solution I found is the following (not very beautiful) awk-script on git diff:

```
git diff HEAD~1 HEAD\
|awk '/^diff/{sub(/[^\/]*\//,"",$3);a=$3;getline;print $1, a}'
```

Output:

```
deleted file1
index mydir/file2
new file3
```

More beautiful solutions are still welcome!